# How do I update the innerHTML of a div with the contents of a JS array after pushing new items into it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I have an array with three items in it, and four buttons - each adds a new item to the array.

Pushing items into the array with the buttons is working fine, but, as for the div where the items are displayed, it does not update correctly. The first item I push always shows up on the div correctly, but from there on, everytime I click on one of the remaining buttons, the same items shows up.

What am I doing wrong here?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lpbjryg/)

```js
var inventory = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"];

for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
  document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML += inventory[i] + "<br>";

function addItem(newItem, itemBtn) {
  inventory.push(newItem);
  document.getElementById(itemBtn).style.display = "none";
  console.log(inventory);
  document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML += inventory[i] + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p>Fruits:</p>
<div id="arrayDiv"></div>
<hr>
<input id="banana" type="button" value="Banana" onclick="addItem('Banana', 'banana')">
<input id="melon" type="button" value="Melon" onclick="addItem('Melon', 'melon')">
<input id="pineapple" type="button" value="Pineapple" onclick="addItem('Pineapple', 'pineapple')">
<input id="coconut" type="button" value="Coconut" onclick="addItem('Coconut', 'coconut')">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inventory[i]` the variable **`i`** is fixed to one value after your `for loop` is executed.

After loop prints ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"] the value of **`i`** is now stuck at 3.

(Apple => 0, Pear => 1, Orange => 2), hence the next value on **`i`** is 3 due to `i++` of the `for loop`

Thus, you can be getting the same Fruit name displayed in HTML.

To avoid that problem, just use `newItem` instead of `inventory[i]`.

```js
var inventory = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"];

for (i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
  document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML += inventory[i] + "<br>";

function addItem(newItem, itemBtn) {
   
  inventory.push(newItem);
  document.getElementById(itemBtn).style.display = "none";
  
  document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML += newItem + "<br>";
}
```

```html
<p>Fruits:</p>
<div id="arrayDiv"></div>
<hr>
<input id="banana" type="button" value="Banana" onclick="addItem('Banana', 'banana')">
<input id="melon" type="button" value="Melon" onclick="addItem('Melon', 'melon')">
<input id="pineapple" type="button" value="Pineapple" onclick="addItem('Pineapple', 'pineapple')">
<input id="coconut" type="button" value="Coconut" onclick="addItem('Coconut', 'coconut')">
```

Answer (score 0):

i is not changing because the loop was executed (3 is your initial array length);

you can update the code so it will look for the last index. try this:

```
function addItem(newItem, itemBtn) {
   inventory.push(newItem);
   document.getElementById(itemBtn).style.display = "none";
   var lastItemIndex = inventory.length - 1;
   document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML += inventory[lastItemIndex] + "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the index `i` is global. When your loop ran first time, the loop exited when `i` became 3 and well it stayed that way from there on. So whatever you add the first time will now be at that `i` value. Now whenever you add it again, the item you first added which is at index 3 is the one you always end up adding to the dom but your array will be updated correctly since it didn't rely on the `i` value.

Also though there will be approaches shared in other answers to help you out with this scenario. You can also try something like below making use of **Document Fragment** and relying less on the `innerHTML` bit and more on **DOM** APIs like `.append`, `createTextNode` etc.

The only reason this approach is useful is because the no of HTML nodes rendered on screen depend on the items you have inside `inventory`. `renderInventory` will always work on basis of `inventory` (like single source of truth).

```js
var inventory = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange"];

function renderInventory(){
  document.getElementById("arrayDiv").innerHTML = '';
  const df = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (let i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
{
   const textNode = document.createTextNode(`${inventory[i]}\n`);
   df.append(textNode);
}
document.getElementById("arrayDiv").append(df);
}

function addItem(newItem, itemBtn) {
  inventory.push(newItem);
  document.getElementById(itemBtn).style.display = "none";
  renderInventory();
}
```

```css
#arrayDiv{
white-space:pre
}
```

```html
<p>Fruits:</p>
<div id="arrayDiv"></div>
<hr>
<input id="banana" type="button" value="Banana" onclick="addItem('Banana', 'banana')">
<input id="melon" type="button" value="Melon" onclick="addItem('Melon', 'melon')">
<input id="pineapple" type="button" value="Pineapple" onclick="addItem('Pineapple', 'pineapple')">
<input id="coconut" type="button" value="Coconut" onclick="addItem('Coconut', 'coconut')">
```